# anybody using D-Link xStack enterprise switches?

Tags: networking, switch, d-link

Is there anybody out there using D-Link's xStack enterprise switches ? I have run into some snags and would appreciate exchanging notes with other admins using the same switches. What kind of switch do you have and what have you used them for ? thanks.

Comment: RE: exchanging notes with other admins - If you have specific questions you should probably update your question and ask them.

Comment: When I see "d-link" and "enterprise" in the same sentence, my "huh?" meter goes off.  Usually when I think "enterprise" I'm thinking Cisco, HP ProCurve, 3Com, etc.  D-Link has always been associated with consumer products in my mind.  I wasn't aware they made "enterprise" switches.  I'll have to check them out.

Comment: That makes you want to check them out and not run away? :)

If you want cheap managed switches, the HP 1800-24G switches are under 300USD.

Comment: Most of my encounters with d-link products were bad experiences. Switches/routers overheating, hanging under load, wifi routers dropping connections randomly. There's enough good hardware providers in the market for me not to even consider buying d-link.

Answer (score 1):

I was working in ISP company. We were using 3526 switches, but then switched to 3028(for clients) + 3100 (on aggregation) because it's cheaper and we didn't used xstack (it was pretty buggy at that time).

D-Link is cheap, have good warranty and support(i can speak for Russia only) so it's good for small local ISPs like ours. But D-Link also have many firmware bugs (once upon a time we have to directly reboot 300 switches 'cause of some nasty firmware error) so if you want to make good choice for big enterprise - switch to HP/3Com (or Cisco if you have $$ you want to invest in network infrastructure).

PS. all problems we ran into with d-link equipment were solved on local d-link support forum in 1-3 days.